# Transferring A VM Image To Someone, Privacy Concern

Tags: vmware

Im setting up a Windows 7 VM and will be optimizing / setting up a suite of proprietary software/settings including a VPN. I will also be connecting this VM to the internet (through a VPN) from my local internet connection for further work online. This will be done on my local PC for a customer. The end product is a VM with proprietary software installed with a VPN so the customer can easily use the software and connect to the VPN.

Once this is complete I'd like to drop this VM image in a cloud storage so the customer can download the image to their local PC and run the image. The software suite and settings takes roughly 3 days to complete and cannot be done by the customer.

My concern:

This is a private transaction and for security/privacy I would not like the customer to know my IP. Since the Windows 7 VM will be running on my local PC and connecting to the internet (a VPN) using my local internet I am sure records will be present on the machine showing my local IP.

Questions:

1) How can I ensure no record of my local IP is saved so I can safely transfer this VM to the customer?

2) Alternatively, how difficult would it be to allow a remote connection on a windows 7 VM so I can have the customer create the image on their local machine and I connect remotely and install/setup the software and VPN suite this way? Would the customer see my IP if do this with a remote connection?

Comment: Possible approach: set VM network adapter to "network bridge" and set up (and connect to) a network connection on host not showing your IP. Though, don't ask me how.

Comment: this looks not pretty!! why I would be worried if my customer has accidentally or purposely known my IP?